# How do Assignment Expressions `:=` work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I've read [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) about assignment expressions and I found this code to be a clear example where I could use it:

```
while line := fp.readline():
    do_stuff(line)
```

But I am confused, from what I read, it is supposed to work just like normal assignment but return the value. But it doesn't appear to work like that:

```
>>> w:=1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    w:=1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now after tinkering with it I realised the following works:

```
>>> (w:=1)
1
```

But it feels so unpythonic. It is the only operator that requires parentheses:

```
>>> w = 1
>>> w + w
2
>>> w == w
True
>>> w is w
True
>>> w < w
False
```

Is there a reason for it to be treated by the parser differently than literally anything else in Python...? I feel like I am missing something. This is not just an operator.

It would be super useful to use `:=` in the REPL to assign variables as the value would be displayed.

---

(Update:
I do not encourage opinionated discussion on this sensitive topic. Please avoid posting comments or answers other than useful ones.)

Comment: OMG this is so evil...

Comment: @PhilipTzou I felt the same when I saw it for the first time, but it is readable and quite useful.

Comment: But now we have two ways for variable assignment (although the := is not recommended in the PEP).

Comment: PEP 572 [actually covers this case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) - it's to avoid ambiguity. That said, I'm not sure what this question is discussing (feature seems to be working as intended?), and I don't think StackOverflow is the correct place for that discussion.

Comment: The `while line := fp.readline():` is also non-sense. It can be simply replaced by a more pythonic way `for line in fp.readline():` or even `for line in fp:`.

Comment: It's not  in a release yet, is it?

Comment: I thought about why they didn't decide to make assignment an expression, like e.g. C does it, [and I have found their arguments against it pretty weak](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#why-not-just-turn-existing-assignment-into-an-expression). It's probably more of a political decision, maintaining an "easy to learn and use language". But then you end up with a lot of special cases for everything. PHP should be a warning to that, when they realized they needed a "real" comparison operator, and now it has `==` and `===`.

Comment: @hpaulj It is in [pre-release](https://www.python.org/download/pre-releases/)

Comment: Interestingly, some of the supposedly invalid usage examples [seem to work for me](https://gist.github.com/myrmica-habilis/5f89c56dc5d97a6269c8edea682f9c5a) in the current alpha version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [GreenCloakGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648811/green-cloak-guy) mentioned, it is there to avoid confusion, as said [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases), I think this line sums it all:

> there is no syntactic position where both = and := are valid.

It also makes things like these invalid because too confusing:

```
y0 = y1 := f(x)
foo(x = y := f(x))
```